# .htaccess URL rewrite not working

Tags: http, iis, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

Why doesnt this script work for /ProjectProfiles?

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.79

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !(cp|img|files|js|css|index\.php|x|flat|robots\.txt|file\.html|uploadfile\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Log:

```
147240/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /x/email2image.php?prefix=sales
(1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/x/email2image.php'
(4) RewriteCond: input='/x/email2image.php' pattern='(favicon.ico|cp|img|files|js|css|index\.php|x|flat|robots\.txt|file\.html|uploadfile\.php)' => not-matched

---------- WHY DOESNT THIS WORK?? --------------------------
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /ProjectProfiles
(1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/ProjectProfiles'
(4) RewriteCond: input='/ProjectProfiles' pattern='(favicon.ico|cp|img|files|js|css|index\.php|x|flat|robots\.txt|file\.html|uploadfile\.php)' => not-matched
------------------------------------------------------------

(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /ContactUs
(1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/ContactUs'
(4) RewriteCond: input='/ContactUs' pattern='(favicon.ico|cp|img|files|js|css|index\.php|x|flat|robots\.txt|file\.html|uploadfile\.php)' => matched
(1) Rewrite URL to >> /index.php//ContactUs
(2) rewrite '/ContactUs' -> '/index.php//ContactUs'
(2) internal redirect with /index.php//ContactUs [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ProjectProfiles contains "files". Depending on how you intend your other matches to work, try e.g.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/(cp|img|files|js|css|index\.php|x|flat|robots\.txt|file\.html|uploadfile\.php)$
```

Comment: It answers the question. As his patterns show, he knows how to use ^ and $ and can easily fix the RewriteCond. But, I'll edit in a RewriteCond.

Comment: His log indicates $1 contains the /

Comment: Yes, I just saw that. (In Apache `.htaccess` it wouldn't.)

Comment: Actually I inherited this config a while back and just add dir's as i need, im not that savey with these, can anyone tell me how I would make "files" specific ie. "/files/" so that it isnt picked up inside projectproFiles - Thanks

Comment: Just use `|/files|` inside the RewriteCond